# jQuery replace multiple occurrences of substring/text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, replace, replaceall

I am currently trying to learn a `replace`method in jQuery.

I have a `<div class="notes">` with the following text

```
  (1 1 1 0 0 1 1)(1 1 1 0 0 1 1)(1 1 1 0 0 1 1)(1 1 1 0 0 0 0)(1 1 1 0 0 1 1)
```

and would like to replace the text with certain values. For example, each time I see `)(`, I would want it to go to a new line (`<br/>`). I was attempting to use jQuery's replace method to achieve this.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    var text = $('.notes').html().replace(")(", "<br/>");
    $('.notes').html(text);
  });
```

I noted that when doing this, it was only replacing the first instance. So I tried a `replaceAll` method, although this had no effect on the string.

[Quick fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/jsbutler483/eLkxyptv/) or snippet below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var text = $('.notes').html().replace(")(", "<br/>");
    $('.notes').html(text);
    alert(text);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="notes">
  (1 1 1 0 0 1 1)(1 1 1 0 0 1 1)(1 1 1 0 0 1 1)(1 1 1 0 0 0 0)(1 1 1 0 0 1 1)
</div>
```

Could anyone advise as to how I should go about this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use a regular expression instead which runs globally, notice the `/g` command.

For your case, you'll need to use the following:

```
/\)\(/g
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var text = $('.notes').html().replace(/\)\(/g, "<br/>");
    $('.notes').html(text);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="notes">
  (1 1 1 0 0 1 1)(1 1 1 0 0 1 1)(1 1 1 0 0 1 1)(1 1 1 0 0 0 0)(1 1 1 0 0 1 1)
</div>
```

Comment: He only needs the `g` modifier, `replace()` method converts automatically to regexp if you pass a string. Good answer, but not well explained

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude Ahh okay, I'm still new to regex myself

Comment: Yeah, you can write the same with the OP's code: `replace(")(", "<br/>", "g");`. Note the last parameter, is the flags parameter. With this you gottcha now. The first parameter is an string, but replace method converts it to a regular expression. That's why if you don't put the `g` flag it doesn't replace globally.

Comment: Ahh thanks for the clarification, will add it to the answer and credit :)

Comment: You are welcome, never will go to bed without learning something new. You have more info here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Answer (score 4):

`.replace()` is a String method and not a jQuery method, so a simple RegExp should do.

```
 var text = $('.notes').html().replace(/\)\(/g, "<br/>");
```

Notice the `g` command that stands for global, which means it applies to all instances.

Answer (score 3):

Here you go -

Here, `/\(|\)/g` is a regex (regular expression). The flag `g` means global. It causes all matches to be replaced.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var text = $('.notes').text().replace(/\(|\)/g, "<br/>");
    $('.notes').html(text);
    alert(text);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="notes">
  (1 1 1 0 0 1 1)(1 1 1 0 0 1 1)(1 1 1 0 0 1 1)(1 1 1 0 0 0 0)(1 1 1 0 0 1 1)
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

a answer wihtout regex (split and join):

```
$(function() {
    var notes = $('.notes');
    notes.html(notes.html().split(')(').join(')<br/>('));
});
```

Comment: Q. Would this be heavy if there were hundreds of `)(` compared to regex?

Comment: i don't think so, try it 'var s = ''; for(var n = 0; n < 10000; n++) s += '(1 0 0 0 1)'; s.split(')(').join(')<br/>(');`

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.notes').html($('.notes').html().replace(/\)\(/g, '<br />'));
});
```